# IXAmlTypeResolver.Resolve failing in Blend

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls, expression-blend

I'm attempting to do some type resolution inside of a WPF Markup Extension using the same namespace:StaticType.Property syntax that StaticExtension uses. The extension works fine at runtime and also in the Visual Studio designer, but it fails in Expression Blend. After some debugging I figured out that the failure occurs in a call to IXamlTypeResolver.Resolve().

```
// Parse Static=properties:Resources.HelloWorld like static resource
int index = this.Static.IndexOf('.');
if (index == -1)
    throw new ArgumentException(Resources.InvalidStaticBindingSyntax + ": " + 
                                this.Static);

// resolve properties:Resources
string typeName = this.Static.Substring(0, index);
IXamlTypeResolver service = _serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IXamlTypeResolver))
                            as IXamlTypeResolver;

Type memberType = service.Resolve(typeName);

string propName = this.Static.Substring(index + 1);
localized = memberType.GetProperty(propName,
                       BindingFlags.Public | 
                       BindingFlags.Static | 
                       BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy)
                       .GetValue(memberType, null);
```

The problem is the service.Resolve(typeName) which fails, but only in Blend.

Took a look at the StaticExtension with Reflector and the code MS is using doesn't look much different.

It looks like a security issue - but I've even tried to sign and GAC the assembly and it still fails exactly the same.

Stumped.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the designer uses a completly different implementation than WPF runtime. There's a bug on Microsoft Connect for this issue.

I wrote a workaround for this problem that solves your particular issue and could be distributed with WPF Localization Guidance.

I created a wrapper called ExpressionWorkaroundServiceProvider which can be used like this:

```
// resolve properties:Resources
string typeName = this.Static.Substring(0, index);
string propName = this.Static.Substring(index + 1);

IServiceProvider serviceProvider = new ExpressionWorkaroundServiceProvider(_serviceProvider)
{
    PropertyName = propName
};

IXamlTypeResolver service = serviceProvider.GetService(typeof(IXamlTypeResolver))
                        as IXamlTypeResolver;

Type memberType = service.Resolve(typeName);

this._propertyInfo = memberType.GetProperty(propName,
                BindingFlags.Public |
                BindingFlags.Static |
                BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy |
                BindingFlags.NonPublic);
```

The implementation of the ExpressionWorkaroundServiceProvider:

```
internal class ExpressionWorkaroundServiceProvider : IServiceProvider, IXamlTypeResolver
{
    private IServiceProvider _originalProvider;

    public string PropertyName { get; set; }

    public ExpressionWorkaroundServiceProvider(IServiceProvider originalProvider)
    {
        if (originalProvider == null)
        {
            throw new ArgumentNullException("originalProvider");
        }

        _originalProvider = originalProvider;
    }

    public object GetService(Type serviceType)
    {
        var servicedObject = _originalProvider.GetService(serviceType);

        if (servicedObject == null && serviceType == typeof(IXamlTypeResolver))
        {
            return this;
        }

        return servicedObject;
    }

    public Type Resolve(string qualifiedTypeName)
    {
        var typeName = qualifiedTypeName.Substring(qualifiedTypeName.IndexOf(':') + 1);

        var types =
            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies().Aggregate(new List<Type>(),
                (list, asm) =>
                {
                    list.AddRange(asm.GetTypes().Where(p => p.Name.Contains(typeName)));
                    return list;
                });

        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(PropertyName))
        {
            return types.FirstOrDefault();
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (var type in types)
            {
                if (type.GetProperty(PropertyName,
                        BindingFlags.Public |
                        BindingFlags.Static |
                        BindingFlags.FlattenHierarchy |
                        BindingFlags.NonPublic) != null)
                {
                    return type;
                }
            }

            return null;
        }           
    }
}
```

This solved the problem for me. It's not a substitute to a correct IXamlTypeResolver implementation but will get the localization working on the designer.